# What's the origin of the Chinese Farmer story?

Tags: alan-watts

[Alan Watts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Watts) told *[The Story of the Chinese Farmer](https://wellsbaum.blog/alan-watts-story-of-the-chinese-farmer/)*, which is also sometimes found under the title *Maybe*. It appears that he told this story sometime between 1960-1969, since it was published in Watts, A. (2011). *Eastern wisdom, modern life: Collected talks: 1960-1969*. New World Library.

**Is there any history of this story before Watts?** Is there a similar story that it might have been based upon? On the other hand, has some scholar researched this question and concluded that Watts wrote it himself?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_old_man_lost_his_horse#Potential_origin,_chengyu,_proverbs,_and_delimitations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be earlier renditions, but this story is in the [Huainanzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huainanzi) compiled around 139 BCE:

> 近塞上之人有善術者，馬無故亡而入胡，人皆弔之 。其父曰：此何遽不為福乎
>
> Among the people who lived close to the border, there was a man who
>   led a righteous life. Without reason, his horse escaped, and fled into
>   barbarian territory. Everyone pitied him, but the old man said : "what
>   makes you think this is not a good thing?"
>
> 居數月，其馬將胡駿馬而歸，人皆賀之。其父曰：此何遽不能為禍乎
>
> Several months later, his horse returned, accompanied by a superb
>   barbarian stallion. Everyone congratulated him. But the old man said:
>   "what makes you think this is cannot be a bad thing?"
>
> 家富良馬，其子好騎，墮而折其髀，人皆弔之。其父曰：此何遽不為福乎
>
> The family was richer from a good horse, his son enjoyed riding it. He
>   fell and broke his hip. Everyone pitied him, but the old man said:
>   "what makes you think this is not a good thing!"
>
> 居一年，胡人大入塞，丁壯者引弦而戰，近塞之人，死者十九，此獨以跛之故，父子相保
>
> One year later, a large party of barbarians entered the border. All
>   the valid men drew their bows and went to battle. From the people
>   living around the border, nine out of ten died. But just because he
>   was lame, the old man and his son were both spared.
>
> 故福之為禍，禍之為福，化不可極，深不可測也。
>
> Thence, good fortune turns into bad fortune, and bad fortune turns
>   into good fortune. These changes never reach an end, their complexity
>   can never be fathomed.